# View animations with applyTransformaiton and interpolated time issue

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to do a simple expand view animation.
I have a TextView that is set to wrap content.
When I use my expandHeight() method, I override applyTransformation to expand the view's height.

This is the applayTransformation method:

```
       protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            Log.d("LOGGY", "interpolated: " + interpolatedTime);
            if (interpolatedTime >= 1.0){
                v.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            }

            v.requestLayout();
        }
```

Simple. Yet, even on simple layouts, the TextView that expands stutters.
When I check Logcat for the interplatedTime value this is what I get:

```
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 0.0
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 0.0
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 0.17647204
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 0.5564282
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 0.8852566
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 1.0
D/LOGGY﹕ interpolated: 1.0
```

Obviously, there are huge hops between each call. 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1

I looked every where for a solution for smoother animations... found none.
And yet, when I look at some of google's apps... smoothest animations ever.
What is it? Magic?

Please assist...

Comment: What Interpolator did you use? LinearInterpolator? and whats the duration of the animation?

Comment: I tried LinearInterpolator (which is also the default one) and AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator. AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator seems to be a bit smoother but it still stutters. Animation duration is 250ms.

Comment: so you have 5 * 4 frame rate,  not that bad, btw the default is ADI not LI

Comment: It looks horrible. 20fps is no frame rate. 60 is frame rate.
And setInterpolator() defaults to Linear...

Comment: so 24fps is no fps? it seems to be a tv standard...  and interpolator defaults to like i sad ADI,  see Animation.ensureInterpolator() method

Comment: pskink, any useful advice? Or are you still trying to prove your opinion :)

Comment: yes,  if its slow try to make a custom ViewGroup so that it lays out children faster

Comment: the problem is with the duration, try to set the duration to 500 or bigger, then you will notice it will be smoother

Comment: and @pskink is right, the default interpolator is AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator

Comment: Thank you both!
I tried setting duration to 500 and there was some improvement. Setting the time to 1000 looked really smooth but it was way to slow..
So I'll try to create a custom view group, or stay with 500ms... which is both ok and not too slow.
Another issue here is the soft keyboard. Expanding and collapsing the TextView makes the keyboard move up and down which in turn kinda breaks the animation. And also leaves an ugly white gap when the move occurs.
It's amazing how complicated it becomes to do such a simple UI animation in Android.

Comment: Another thing that is worth mentioning regarding the keyboard that helped is to make sure suggestions are turned off using inputType=textFilter.  This will stop the "keyboard hopping" issue.